# Alamofire Content-Type application/json for PUT method

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm now finding solution for add `content-type: application/json` in Alamofire Content-Type application/json for PUT method. I've developed as follow, but not working correctly.

```
        Alamofire.request(.PUT, Config.preferenceURL, parameters: param, headers: headers)
            .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
                print(swiftyJsonVar)
                if (swiftyJsonVar["success"]) {

                }

                JHProgressHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
        }
```

Comment: Show/add the error log what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `encoding: .JSON` in your `request` method. Otherwise it will encode your parameters as query parameters in the URL. By using `.JSON` encoding, the `Content-Type` header will be set for you automatically.

```
Alamofire.request(.PUT, Config.preferenceURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
```

You can also use the `debugPrint` API to print out the `cURL` command equivalent to the request you're sending to the server.

```
let request = Alamofire.request(.PUT, Config.preferenceURL, parameters: param, encoding: .JSON, headers: headers)
debugPrint(request)
```

Cheers.

Comment: *"`Content-Type` header will be set for you automatically."* Is this changed on 4.0? I had to add it manually even if I use `JSONEncoding.default`

Answer (score 0):

Add `content-type: application/json` look like this:-

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/post")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

do {
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
} catch {
    // No-op
}

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
```

[More detail here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)